# Radial svg slider height

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using Radial svg slider from codyhouse and I want to increase its height on mobile devices (small screens)

heres the slider implementation:
https://codyhouse.co/gem/radial-svg-slider/

and here is a demo that shows the slider on action:
https://codyhouse.co/demo/radial-svg-slider/index.html

Comment: https://codepen.io/Fitrepreneur/pen/yaJGzA?editors=1100

Comment: add this comment to your question ^^